# How to compare specified type element of the array?

Tags: arrays, compare, contains, equality

I have a extension method to judge if an item exists in the array/list.

I encountered a problem that **how to judge the equality between two elements if the T is an Array/List?**

Suppose `[1, 2]` and `[2, 1]` are two different elements.
Here is my method:

```
public static bool ContainsElement<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, T target, out T matched)
{
    matched = default(T);

    if (typeof(T).IsCollection())
    {
        var targetElements = (target as IEnumerable).Cast<object>();
        foreach (var element in list)
        {
            var innerElements = (element as IEnumerable).Cast<object>();
            if (targetElements.Count() == innerElements.Count())
            {
                bool findDifference = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < targetElements.Count(); i++)
                {
                    if (/* How to compare the two element */)
                    {
                        findDifference = true;
                    }
                }

                if (!findDifference)
                {
                    matched = element;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var element in list)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(element, target))
            {
                matched = element;
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I cannot find the way to know **How to create a `EqualityComparer<>` for the element of the `T` array**.
I can just get the type of element via typeof(T).GetElementType(), but it seems no use to compare the two element.

By the way, the **IsCollection** method is my extension method to check if the T is array or assigned from IEnumerable.

Can you help me?